# In Vim statusline, right-pad number

Tags: vim, statusline

Say I do `set statusline+=col:%3v;` in Vim 8.

Now if I'm on column 1, my statusline looks like `col:  1;`.

How do I get the padding on the other side of the number? E.g., how do I get my column 1 statusline to look like `col:1   ;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `%-3v`. As documented in `:help 'statusline`:

```
field       meaning  
-           Left justify the item.  The default is right justified
            when minwid is larger than the length of the item.
```

This is also the convention used by `printf`, which vim is clearly imitating.

Comment: Huh, I scanned through the help page and completely missed that.